# Is there a good JSP editor for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, editor, eclipse-plugin

I need a nice JSP editor plugin for Eclipse. What are my choices?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As well as Amateras you could try [Web Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) or [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/).  Although they will both give you way more than just a jsp editor.

**Edit 2010/10/26 (comment from [Simon Gibbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13935/simon-gibbs)):**

The Web Tools Project JSP editor is in the "Web Page Editor (Optional)" project.

**Edit 2016/08/16 (extended comment from [Dan Carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692626/dan-carter)):**

From Kepler (Eclipse 4.3.x) on, this is called "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor".

[image: eclipse]

Comment: FYI: I am currently using Amateras and I FREQUENTLY get stack overflows causing Eclipse to crash in Ganymede.

Comment: The JSP editor seems to come with the plugin called "Web Page Editor (Optional)" which is available via the WTP update site. Not as obvious as it could be.

Comment: +1 for "Web Page Editor (Optional)" -- this works well for jsp editing.

Comment: In kepler this is now called "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor"

Comment: There is no Web Page Editor any more (in the update dialog at least). Using Kepler, I had to set it the default for .jsp inside eclipse editor settings.... and you need to re-open any alrady open jsp files to take effect.

Answer (score 74):

I followed the advice of Simon Gibbs in this answer and found it worked out fine - if you're in a hurry, the "Web Page Editor (optional)" package from the Eclipse update site does the trick.

For the Eclipse-challenged (me) Help > Install New Software > Work with  > Expand Web, XML, and Java EE Development > Select "Web Page Editor (optional)" and "next-through" to completion.

Comment: thanks, it's always nice to have the full instructions of what to do.

Comment: For Indigo... Work with: Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo -> Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development -> Web Page Editor

Comment: +1 for the detailed instructions for the eclipse challenged

Comment: For Helios... http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/ -> Web, XML, Java EE Development -> Web Page Editor (Optional)

Comment: In kepler this is now called "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor"

Comment: I don't see a 'works with'

Answer (score 5):

"Web Page Editor (optional)" package from the Eclipse Galileo/Helios update site has the following very minor quirks in a JSP editor:

- Auto-commenting in Java code fragments does not work (Ctrl /); [fixed in Helios SR2]
- [present in Galileo, fixed in Eclipse Helios SR1] If a Java code fragment has errors that are already fixed, the editor does not remove the error marks until you modify the erroneous place or close/reopen the file being edited;

This was valid at Dec 7, 2010.

Comment: WTP has many problems ,CSS code completion not exist ! js validation has many problems ,jsp refactoring in form elements not safe ,Code sorting and autoformat is terrible

Answer (score 3):

You could check out JBoss Tools plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this one, it's open source http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor

Answer (score 1):

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/) has a pretty decent one, it costs money however. One of the reasons I went over to Netbeans is because of their JSP editor, which is still far from perfect but better then vanilla Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Bravo JSP Editor  (Can't comment on how good it is, i haven't tried it)
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bravo-jsp-editor

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) on the deployed files

Answer (score -1):

[Oracle Workshop for Weblogic](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/workshop/index.html) is supposed to have a pretty nice jsp editor but I've never used it.  You needn't be using Weblogic to use it.