# Eclipse: formatting JavaScript Snippet embedded in JSP

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, format

Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+F` on a JSP editor in eclipse  only formats the codes within html tags and jsp tags.

But my JSP file has a lots of JavaScript( unformatted) embedded using `<script> </script>`. So it very difficult to read the JavaScript code.

***My Question is:***

Is there any **plugin or any other way** to format those embedded JavaScript along with the HTML/JSP codes to make them readable?

If anyone has already figured out a way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: It's better to place js code in external files. Not only because of problems with syntax highlighting. Otherwise, you'll get a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken of code.

Comment: Actually that type of coding was done by some other people, and now we are maintaining it. its very difficult to read the codes unformatted code. Anyway thanks for suggestion.

Comment: And thanks for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken :D. Never heard of it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems there is no such way to Format the javascript code mixed into jsp.

Anyway, you can use following simple trick.

- extract the javascript code into a .js file, format it there and copy the formatted code back to main file.

Answer (score 0):

First, affirming the important point provided by kirilloid above: avoid JS in HTML/JSP files.

Second, look at the SO discussion [Is there a good JSP editor for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse?rq=1) for further information. Short answer: the Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP) will format JavaScript in your JSPs.