# how to config the way EclipseIDE format my JSP codes

Tags: eclipse, jsp, code-formatting

I'm working in a JSP project and my team's working with Eclipse. We must follow some JSP conventions by our company but I can find where is the Eclipse's "JSP formatter".
Someone know about it? (The way to config how Eclipse format the JSP code)
Please tell me how or just some keyword. Many thanks!

Comment: What kind of formatting do you want? If it's colors only, then 
`Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Structured Text Editors`

If it's not - you need to install external jsp editor.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I'm finding a tool to format the blank-lines, indent and many thins such as <br/> tag must be at the end of any line. 
the <p>, p'content, </p>, <td>, td's content, </td> must be in 3 line although content just has some letter. etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Web Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) of Eclipse. This is available from the basic Eclipse repositories and offers support for configurable JSP editing.

Comment: thanks Dirk
I'm using Eclipse EE. It's come with WTP but the built-in JSP Editor do not satisfy me.

Comment: Well, if the configuration options there (which can be based on HTML or XML editors) do not suffice your needs, probably the editors suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse) help any further.