# JSP visual designer plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, plugins

I noticed that NetBeans 6.x has very nice visual web design environment

[image]

which can help you to make design of your jsp pages by simple dragging and droping components of the web page.

Since I'm not using NetBeans my question is: Is there a some plugin for Eclipse that can provide me a similar possibilities? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse

Comment: I visited that link a 2 week's ago. I haven't found anything similar to NetBeanses JSP visual web designer.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install [Eclipse WTP](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) and create project with [JSF](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/docs/tutorial/JSFTools_1_0_tutorial.html)