# JSP on eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I need to JSP functions on Eclipse for JAVA (not an Eclipse for Java EE Developers Edition).

Since I already installed Eclipse for pure JAVA, I need to install some plugins for
JSP pages.

Comment: just curious,why not just use eclipse for java EE ??

Comment: since I already developed several android APPs as well as pure java applications.

Comment: take look at this, it might help be  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211841/is-there-a-good-jsp-editor-for-eclipse

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Help menu and choose Install New Software.  Look for and install the Eclipse Java Web Developers Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse marketplace is good.You will get all kinda supporting plugins there.
goto
help/Eclipse Market Place